# Не удаляются контролы, созданные в цикле

Tags: java

Путем цикла я создала метки. Мне нужно, чтобы, когда я кликну на них мышкой, они исчезали. Кликнула на одну, она исчезла, на другую и так далее. Но, когда я запускаю, метки не пропадают. Что нужно сделать, чтобы все работало так, как надо?

```
    lol = new JPanel();
    lol.setBounds(10, 47, 974, 693);
    contentPane.add(lol);
    lol.setLayout(null);

    for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++){
        label_2 = new JLabel("");
        label_2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(P.class.getResource("/images/00.png")));
        int w = randomRange(10, 974);
        int r = randomRange(10, 693);
        label_2.setBounds(w, r, 200, 200);
        label_2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                lol.remove(label_2);
            }
        });
        lol.add(label_2);
    }
```

Comment: Закажу себе печать: "Код не работает так, как надо. Полыхаев". Где-то в `MouseEvent` должна быть ссылка на кликнутый контрол. Вот его и надо удалять.

Comment: попробуй уменьшить количество меток, например до 3, и посмотреть, действительно ли никакая метка не пропадает

Comment: Вероятнее всего, последний label таки удаляется..

Comment: ссылка на кликнутый контрол?

Comment: уменьшила, но все равно не работает...

Answer (score 2):

```
lol.remove((JLabel)e.getComponent());
```

или

```
lol.remove((JLabel)e.getSource());
```

Comment: куда нужно это вставить? извините, я плохо разбираюсь.

Comment: "Гусары молчать!" - Вместо Вашей строчки `lol.remove(label_2);`

Comment: вставила, но не помогло...

Comment: а, извините, нет, помогло, как-то странно приходится кликать, но они исчезают! спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

И вариант с циклом для полноты картины:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 50; k++)
{
    JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Label" + k);
    label_2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            lol.remove(label_2);
        }
    });
    lol.add(label_2);
}
```

Разница в том, что переменная `label_2` объявляется внутри цикла, а не снаружи. Поэтому во внутреннем классе используется метка из текущей итерации, а не последняя из созданных.

После `lol.remove(label_2);` в обработчик события можно добавить `frame.repaint();`, если отсутствует постоянная отрисовка в цикле.

Comment: большое спасибо! работает!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в замыкании, а именно в этой строчке:

```
lol.remove(label_2);
```

Когда цикл завершается, в переменной label_2 находится последняя поставленная метка. Когда отрабатывает событие клика, то удаляется только эта последняя метка. Вам нужно изменить способ удаления (а точнее, способ получения нужного экземпляра метки)

Comment: то есть, нужно как-то изменить способ создания меток? или способ удаления.